# Last.fm api doesn't allow to join or login

Tags: last.fm

I'm try to connect to last.fm api, but if i press 'join' or 'login' nothing happens. If i go directly to 'http://www.last.fm/join' or to 'http://www.last.fm/login', my chrome open home page. What's wrong?

Comment: I'm not able to join or login either. Tried both Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS X

Comment: "API key registration isn't available at the moment. Sorry about that. The API pages you're currently seeing are a static snapshot of our old website, with the API key registration and management functionalities not being available there. That you're being redirected to the overview page when trying to log in happens because these pages don't let you log in either, but you would only be able to view your API account page when logged in - so this is why you're seeing this broken behaviour."

Answer (score 4):

**They are not able to accept new API accounts at the moment**.
Here is what their support team said 2 months ago:

> We're currently not able to accept new API accounts at this time --
>   the team are working to add support as soon as possible.
>
> We apologise for any inconvenience caused by this in the meantime.

Customer service added the following 2 weeks ago:

> it's definitely moving forward.

It seems they will re-open soon.

[Source](https://getsatisfaction.com/lastfm/topics/trying-to-apply-for-an-api-key).